# Accept a Confirm box with PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase

Tags: selenium, popup, phpunit

I have found a ton of solutions in other languages but not with php, any suggestions?, I thought I could just use $this->keysSpecial('ENTER'); when it pops up but if i understand it it stops the selenium test when a popup apears.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->acceptAlert();`

I had this same problem last week and it took me hours to find the solution. I tried the `keysSpecial('ENTER')`, I tried `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation()` which I found out they didn't implement in php.

I wish I had bookmarked where I found it, phpunit Selenium documentation is awful and you get downvoted to oblivion when you ask questions about it.

Hope that was what you were looking for!

Comment: This would be the exact thing i am looking for yes, but my test just stop when the confirm box open and then when I close it manually I get "PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandle
d inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"No JavaScript dialog to handle"}"